# XslCompiledTransform Line Break, How can I input them?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xslcompiledtransform

Using the following code:

```
XDocument transformedDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = transformedDoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            //transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/CareLog.xsl"))));
            transform.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/CareLog.xsl"));
            transform.Transform(doc.CreateReader(), writer);
        }
```

I have some strings from a database that contain `<br />` for a line return(as used elsewhere).  Whatever I replace this with, Environment.NewLine, \n, etc it will never put line breaks in the transformed document.

EDIT

Replaced line breaks with \r\n and changed as per suggestion below:

```
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/CareLogresidenceSummary.xsl"));
var settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
settings.NewLineChars = "\n";
using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/BrowserTemp/CareLogResidenceSummary.xml"), settings))
    {
        xslt.Transform(reader, writer);
    }
}
```

Still creates transformed document ok, but still does not put anything onto a new line. For reference I am renaming the transformed document with a .doc extension to open in word, the XML has the line breaks but not when opened in Word.

Comment: It was answered a long time ago(!), but did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: It didn't I had to create word document itself but I will mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "\r\n" for representing new lines.

There are two ways you can handle the newlines:

1. Set-up the writer to use specific characters when writing new lines using the [NewLineChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars.aspx) option.
2. Instruct the writer not to modify the new lines using the [NewLineHandling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx) option

So you could modify your code as follows to preserve the new lines:

```
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/CareLog.xsl"));
var settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
settings.NewLineChars = "\n";
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("example.xml"))
{
 using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("yourDoc.txt", settings))
 {
   xslt.Transform(reader, writer);
 }
}
```

Note that I haven't run this. The only thing you'll need to do is get your file into the call to "XmlWriter.Create()".

Comment: Try setting the NewLineHandling option, e.g. something like "settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace". Investigate the options specified in the NewLineHandling article.

Comment: Nope makes no difference

Comment: Can you include your XML and XSL in the question?

Comment: The XML is created dynamically, do you want the finished/transformed document?

Comment: @user1166905 No I wouldn't need the full XML, but it would be good to see a cut down version of the XML and XSL so we can get a good idea of exactly what your trying to achieve and where the problem lies.